# Parallel Fibonacci from "Parallel and Concurrent Haskell"

Tags: haskell, parallel-processing

From Simon Marlow's [Parallel and Concurrent Haskell](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000929/ch02.html#sec_par-eval-whnf), he shows the following example (`rpar.hs`):

```
fib :: Integer -> Integer
fib 0 = 1
fib 1 = 1
fib n = fib (n-1) + fib (n-2)

main = do
  [n] <- getArgs
  let test = [test1,test2,test3,test4] !! (read n - 1)
  t0 <- getCurrentTime
  r <- evaluate (runEval test)
  printTimeSince t0
  print r
  printTimeSince t0

test2 = do
  x <- rpar (fib 36)
  y <- rseq (fib 35)
  return (x,y)
```

Typing in the following from the command-line will run the second test on two cores:

```
$rpar 2 +RTS -N2
time: 0.73s
(24157817,14930352)
time: 1.90s
```

As I understand, the first time represents the time elapsed in order to complete the `rseq (fib 35)`. Then, calling `print r` causes the complete evaluation of `rpar (fib 36)`.

If that explanation is correct, then it seems that `fib 36`'s calculation was not able to re-use the already calculated `fib 35`. In other words, all of the work, i.e. calculating `fib 35`, had to be performed twice.

Is this understanding correct? Please correct or elaborate on anything that I missed.

Comment: Your understanding is correct. The compiler is not even aware that a call to `fib 36` will contain a call to `fib 35`. If you want sharing, you will have to implement it yourself. GHC doesn't do any CSE, because it isn't an optimization in general. Note that `x` and `y` are evaluated in parallel - 0.73s is the time to compute fib 35, and 1.9s is the time to compute fib 36.